# Folder with PySimpleGUI?

Tags: pysimplegui

How to create a folder in local drive with PySimpleGUI ?
[sg.FileSaveAs(" Load Keys ", size=(20, 2), key="-LOAD-", target=r'C:\load_keys', file_types=None),
sg.ProgressBar(100, orientation='h', size=(25, 20), key='-PB-', bar_color='blue on white', expand_x=False),
sg.Text('   Status: ', k='-STATUS-'),
sg.Text('No status', k='-NO_STATUS-')
],

Comment: Hello Boris.  Sorry, but I cannot understand your question.  In general, the specialized buttons like `FileSaveAs`, `FileBrowse`, and `FolderBrowse` have a limited functionality.  You are asking how to use FileSaveAs in a way that can create a subfolder?

Comment: Thanks, but I already found a way to create a folder in windows by python: using the next command: shutil.copytree(source_dir, destination_dir)